# iPhone headphone output - mono control left / right ear

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, ios6

I'm working on an iOS6 and above GPS navigation route creation and following app. At the moment I've integrated the OpenEARS framework to provide text to speech directions to the user.

I have setup an AVAudioSession and overrode the audio category to headphones. I'm looking for some advice in limiting my audio output to the left / right headphone channel depending on what physical direction the user must travel to reach the destination.

This is my first foray into Audio on iOS and am happy to change from OpenEARS if someone has knowledge of completing this with another TTS library.

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone it may help in the future...

After spending hours looking at Core Audio and AudioToolbox methods for balancing I stumbled over a pan property within AVAudioPlayer. OpenEARS, and ultimately Flite, TTS systems use the AVAudioPlayer to play the converted audio file. Cheers!

> The audio player’s stereo pan position.
>
> @property float pan Discussion By setting this property you can
>   position a sound in the stereo field. A value of –1.0 is full left,
>   0.0 is center, and 1.0 is full right.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 4.0 and later. Declared In
>   AVAudioPlayer.h

Comment: Thank you!  I've spent hours learning Audio Units just to do this simple thing.

Comment: is this only for video and not just audio?

Comment: The property is on AVAudioPlayer :)